# How to binding textbox to the list

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox and a textbox, I want the textbox show data according to the listbox selection. The problem is I already have the listbox binding to an object like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name = "listbox" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
```

The textbox which I want to populate data is not the property of `SelectedProduct` that I binding to, it only has relation to the listbox index. For example:

```
private int[] _InputStartAddress = new int[20];
textbox.text = _InputStartAddress[listbox.SelectedIndex];
```

The ViewModel of SelectedProduct:

```
    private Product selectedProduct;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {

        get { return selectedProduct; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedProduct != value)
            {
                selectedProduct = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
         }
     }
```

What should I do to achieve this?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

bind directly  to ListBox property using `ElementName`:

```
<ListBox Name="ListProducts" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=ListProducts}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Sorry for my mistake. SelectedIndex is just an example. The real variable I need to binding is an array according to the SelectedIndex which is `array[SelectedIndex]`.

Comment: include *a real* and *complete* example in the question then

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have reedited my question.

Comment: @BarryLib, I'm still don't understand your scenario. TextBox is supposed to be editable; I don't think it is possible to edit a single array element via binding to TextBox. if `_InputStartAddress` are somehow related to products, they should be a part of product view model (additional property). Then binding will be trivial and editing will work like any other property